# How to debounce user input in reactjs using rxjs

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

My problem may be a trivial one but I wasn't able to find the answer so far.

How can I defer (debounce) updating state in React while user is typing, to avoid unnecessary updates?

Having `<input onChange={this.onChange} .../>`, how can I bind onChange event with rxjs? Should I try to make this input observable or should I use FromEventPattern?

In both cases I have no idea how to bind React events with rxjs. 
The second question is whether the user will see any input changes during debounce?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Solution #1

Using subjects:[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/yubfo636/)

```
const state = new Rx.Subject()
              .debounceTime(1000)
              .scan((acc) => {
                return ++acc
              }, 0).do(::console.log)


const handler = (e) => {        
  state.next(e)
}

state.startWith(0).subscribe((clicks) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<button onClick={handler}>Clicked {clicks}</button>, document.querySelector('#app')) 
})
```

### Solution #2

Using rxjs's fromEvent: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/L1qoo1h5/)

```
// Intial render so element exists in dom (there is probably a better pattern)
ReactDOM.render( <button id='clickMe'>Click Me</button>, document.querySelector('#app')) 

const clicks = Rx.Observable
                .fromEvent(document.getElementById('clickMe'), 'click')
                .do(::console.log)
                .debounceTime(1000)
                .scan((acc) => {
                  return ++acc
                }, 0)

clicks.subscribe((clicks) => {
  ReactDOM.render( <button id='clickMe'>Click Me {clicks}</button>, document.querySelector('#app')) 
})
```

### Solution #3

Note: highly experimental, and just something I tried to do for fun.

This is more for an action based architecture, where you have actions that change your state (flux). This is a handler that is fully standalone. It is used with a custom operator 'fromEventArgs': [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/g6pzze3e/) (look at the console)

```
const handler = (e) => {        
  Rx.Observable
    .fromEventArgs(e, 'UniqueKey') 
    .debounceTime(1000)        
    .subscribe(x => console.log('Send an action', x))
}
```

Comment: thanks, using Subject seems the best fit for me, however instead of scan I just need to subscribe and process the input according to my needs (other than 'fold' semantics).

Comment: Glad to hear. If you think my answer was good, please accept it.

Comment: I can't seem to get Solution #2 to work with the new RXJS, any chance of an update on the answer. This was super helpful, albeit outdated.

Answer (score 9):

based on omerts propositions, (especially solution #1) here is my final code

```
input: Rx.Subject<any>;

constuctor(...){
   this.input = new Rx.Subject();
   this.input.debounce(1000).subscribe(this.processInput);
}

handleChange = event => {
   event.persist();
   this.input.onNext(event);

    };

processInput = x => {
   // invoke redux/flux action to update the state
}

render(){
   ...
   <input onChange={this.handleChange} ... />
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
class MyScene extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        var onChangeTextObservable = Rx.Observable.fromEventPattern(
           (handler) => {this.onChangeText = handler}
        );
        onChangeTextObservable.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
    }

    render() {
       return (
          <TextInput onChangeText={this.onChangeText}>
       )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep getting to this question, while I prefer [this solution from another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44300853/1814970).

Copied below for simplicity. Please upvote the original.

---

> You will need to cretae observable from change events(for example
>   using Subject) and then debounce on that.
>
> Here is the fully featured example for you:

```js
class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: '',
      debounced: '',
    };
    this.onSearch$ = new Rx.Subject();
    this.onSearch = this.onSearch.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.subscription = this.onSearch$
      .debounceTime(300)
      .subscribe(debounced => this.setState({ debounced }));
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
  
  onSearch(e) {
    const search = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ search });
    this.onSearch$.next(search);
  }

  render() {
    const { search, debounced } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={search} onChange={this.onSearch} />
        <div>debounced value: {debounced}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Search />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.4.0/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```