# Rxjs debounce on react text input component using Subjects does not batch input text on stateless/functional component

Tags: javascript, rxjs, debouncing

I'm trying to dive deeper into rxjs and found an issue where the input field I'm trying to debounce dispatches an event on every keypress, the debounce only holds the output but results in a tree like:

```
a
as(delay - waits 200ms, then fires the rest synchronously)
asd
asdf
asdfg 
....
```

The same code works as expected in a class component(https://stackoverflow.com/a/44300853/1356046) but cannot understand why it doesn't work with stateless components. Here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hzhrmf - you can see the useState update fires for every keystroke.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React continuously calls your function to render the component. Therefore the Subject is continuously recreated.

Using a factory with useState to keep the subject and working with useEffect to make sure the subscription is only made once should fix your issue.

Something like this :

```js
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { debounceTime, map, tap, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { fromEvent, Subject } from 'rxjs';

import './style.css';
const App = props => {
  const [queryName, setQueryName] = useState("");
  const [debouncedName, setDebouncedName] = useState("");
  const [onSearch$] = useState(()=>new Subject());
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = onSearch$.pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(a => console.log(a))
    ).subscribe(setDebouncedName);
  }, [])
  const handleSearch = e => {
    setQueryName(e.target.value);
    onSearch$.next(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder="Search Tags"
        value={queryName}
        onChange={handleSearch}
      />
      <p>Debounced: {debouncedName}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, totally makes sense now, I tried moving the subject out of the component but ran into the same issue which makes me believe the re-subscription is the main culprit. I'll play around a bit more for a deeper understanding. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version as custom Hook as this might be used multiple times in a form and can otherwise clutter your code.

```
function useDebounce<T = any>(time: number, defaultValue: T): [T, (v: T) => void] {
  let [value, setValue] = React.useState<T>(defaultValue);
  let [value$] = React.useState(() => new Subject<T>());
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let sub = value$.pipe(debounceTime(time)).subscribe(setValue);
    return () => sub.unsubscribe();
  }, [time, value$]);
 return [value, (v) => value$.next(v)];
}

//useage: 
let [value,setValue] = useDebounce(200,"");
```